# Can mysqldbcompare utility be used on AIX?

Tags: mysql, database, aix, mysqldbcompare

I'm Trying to compare Data between two databases on different servers.
The mysql database are located on 2 AIX boxes.
Im using mysqldbcompare utility to compare the data.
I get the following error:
Server1 connected....
server1 is incompatible . Utility requires 5.1.30 or higher.

I have a higher version utility also installed.
If i run the mysqldbcompare utility on databases based on windows server, it runs fine.

Can I use this mysql utility to connect AIX ?
What other utility can connect AIX based databases?

-thanks for all the help

Comment: What version of MySQL is on each box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like the version of `mysqld` running on your `server1` machine is ancient (before 5.1.30, which was released on 14-Nov-2008).

You obviously can't use the current version of `mysqldbcompare` with that server version.

You might try using an older version of the utility (downloadable from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/).

Or you maybe you can persuade the server's owner to upgrade to a more recent server version.

Or you could use mysqldump to migrate the data you're hoping to examine to a more recent server.

Or, maybe, you're out of luck, sorry to say.

Comment: Thank you for the choices. I was thinking of migrating the data to windows to examine it!